# Moodle Embedded Answers (Cloze) stop duplicate answers

Tags: moodle

I am having difficulty figuring out how to prevent a user from simply typing in the same answer in each embedded Short Answer. I have attached a screenshot of the problem below...

[image: User can enter same answer in each shortanswer box]

Ideally I need Moodle to not accept the same answer twice, is there a correct way to do this? Would a bit of Javascript do the trick?

It seems like this should be a fairly common problem but I havent been able to find anthing to help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If its a Moodle form, then you should be able to add a compare rule. I haven't tried it but something like this :

```
$mform->addRule(array('currentformfieldname', 'previousformfieldname'),
    get_string('duplicateerrormessage', 'langsourcefile'), 'compare', 'neq');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The question is an Embedded Answers (Cloze) question. It is created through the Moodle site using syntax as follows...    

'code'{3:SHORTANSWER:%100%Test~%100%Test1~%100%Test2}
{3:SHORTANSWER:%100%Test~%100%Test1~%100%Test2}
{3:SHORTANSWER:%100%Test~%100%Test1~%100%Test2}'code'

Could the compare rule be used here?

Comment: @MikeyJ Curious to know whether you were able to fix this. I'm also trying to solve same problem now. I see that the answer posted above is not suitable for Cloze questions. I guess you had to customize cloze question type or replace it with Gap-fill question type to achieve what you wanted. The code for Cloze question is not very readable or well documented. I think the code that need customization is inside `<moodle-directory>/question/type/multianswer/question.php` the method named `compute_final_grade`